# Page links won't show

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTML/CSS and I am making a website.

I am trying to put a link at the top of the page, but it isn't showing. According to the browsers developer tools it's there but behind the title. I have given it the highest `z-index` out of all the others. (I know there is a  lot to go through but I have no idea what could be causing the problem.)

Here is my HTML code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #EC7063;
  height: 135px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .9;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

header h1.logo {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  line-height: 200px;
}

header h1.logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.home {
  margin-top: -50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  opacity: .8;
}

div.about {
  background-color: #F5B7B1;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #999;
}

.menu {
  position: static;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 18px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.menu li {
  position: static;
  display: block;
}

.menu li+li {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.menu li a {
  position: static;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img.home_img {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  margin: -5px;
}

.container {
  display: ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Sugar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo">Sugar me</h1>
    <strong><nav>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav></strong>
  </header>
  {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OK, so link overlapdding each other is the only problem in your markup?

Comment: the question is not clear, I can see `{% block content %} {% endblock %}` is showing behind the logo, is this the problem, you can simply wrap it up like `<div style="z-index:1000">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>` and it will show up in front of the header, the links are showing above the header only

Comment: I think so. I am not really sure what the problem is...

Comment: @Daniel So you have some result. I'm asking not about source of problem, I'm asking about your desired result. Is fixing link overlapping will help you and that's the only issue?

Comment: @NarenMurali That din't work.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I would like the two links in front of the header so you can see/click on them

Comment: @Daniel Can you please provide picture of desired result?

Comment: I cannot give a picture of the desired result because I can not get the desired result. I cannot show you a picture of links because the problem is that I cannot see them.

Comment: @Daniel Can you create picture in any image editor?

Comment: link to image http://i.imgur.com/9s4wPcY.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated the page in JSFiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/gme434hp/2/

Changes:
1. to display the list items horizontally I used css "display:inline;" please check the references for the details.

2. I understand that you want to fix the header to the top, so I have added "top:0px" to fix the header to the top.
3. I wrapped the contents of the website

   {% block content %} {% endblock %}

in a container class to show it below the header I added the css "margin-top:135px;" and some other styling so that it will look better and not be hidden behind the header.

please find below the css for the container class.

```
.container {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1000;
  margin-top:135px;
}
```

Whenever you make your website, in the browser press F12 and play around with the CSS properties, this will help you get the desired result faster. Thanks.

Reference: [menu items](https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/)

Comment: whenever I scroll down the header goes very transparent... Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry I forgot the fact that the content needs to be scrollable and should not be showing behind the header - https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/jo65vbz3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove
z-index property and check the result here - https://jsfiddle.net/frvasileva/gev0Let5/

```
.container {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
 /* z-index:1000;*/
  margin-top:135px;
}
```